# Changing placeholder text with CSS only

Tags: css

I am building one of those contact forms that are conversational. I have code that works but I don't think it is optimal (at the bottom). The form looks like:

[image]

The code is live on [this codepen](http://codepen.io/JGallardo/pen/GrrObw)

The problem I was solving was that the placeholder text on one of them is very large and would either break into two lines or if I gave it a fixed width, it would break the layout of smaller mobile phones. Yes, I understand the the very simple solution would be to propose a change to the copy for any instance, but going on the fact that it cannot be done, how would I solve swapping the text based on the device width.

My proposed solution was to reduce the text on mobile. Since there they are more flexible with the mobile product, I can make these changes, but the desktop needs to comply with the PSD.

### HTML

```
<input type="text" id="org" name="" placeholder="ORGANIZATION OR COMPANY NAME">
```

### CSS

```
#org{
  display: block;
  width: 96%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  #org{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 360px;
  }
}
```

It needs to be at least 360px to match the PSD for desktop.

One other option that I have is if I have entirely different inputs, would that work? like

```
<input type="text" id="org" class="orgm" name="" placeholder="ORG/COMPANY">
<input type="text" id="org" class="orgd" name="" placeholder="ORGANIZATION OR COMPANY NAME">


.orgm { //mobile
    display: block;
}
.orgd {
    display: none;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .orgm{
      display: none;
      width: 96%;
      margin: 0 auto;
  }
  .orgd {
      display: inline-block;
      width: 360px;
      margin: 0;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that you are mistaking the purpous of the `placeholder` attribute.

A `label` element should be used to indicate what the field is for and a `placeholder` should provide an example of the format to use.

When you use a seperate `label` you have much more flexability in how you style it. You can use a "label as placeholder" pattern, where you place the 
label on top of the `input` so it appeares to be the placeholder. You would have to move the label when the `input` is focused.

In the snippet below I have created two `lable`'s for the input. It would be very easy to show and hide based on a media query.

```html
<label for="org" class="show-for-large">Organization or Company Name</label>
<label for="org" class="show-for-small" hidden>Org/Company</label>
<input type="text" id="org" name="" placeholder="Code Review">
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the word break and overflow properties and then change the size of the container for the text for your @media query. The result will be a box that hides the rest of the text for different screen sizes rather than change the content. 
You also could make two different p tag elements; one with display: visible the other hidden. Then you can toggle the display properties of these text elements given your @media query results.